# onChanged method of livedata observe called multiple times

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

In my fragment layout file I have a spinner:

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/sp_week"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:entries="@array/week"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:selectedItemPosition="@={TimeSheetFragViewModel.selectedWeek}">
```

And in TimeSheetFragViewModel class I declared the selectedWeek like this:

```
    public MutableLiveData<Integer> selectedWeek = new MutableLiveData<>();

public int getSelectedWeek() {

    if(selectedWeek.getValue() == null) return 0;
    return selectedWeek.getValue();
}

public void setSelectedWeek(int value) {
    selectedWeek.setValue(value);
}
```

In My Fragment I put observer in onActivityCreated for this live data like this:

```
       timeSheetFragViewModel.selectedWeek.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {

            Log.d("DEBUG", "its called");

        }
    });
```

when the fragment is first time loaded the onChanged method called one time. Which I think is okay. However, when i rotate the screen the onChanged method called two times. I need explanation why it is happening.

Comment: Since you are passing new Observer instances, multiple observers are getting registered. You can call removerObserver on LiveData instance, to get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `LiveData` observers are removed in `onDestroy()`. You should note that `onActivityCreated()` can be called multiple times without `onDestroy()` being called. In this scenario every time `onActivityCreate()` is called, the fragment will attach a new observer instance to the LiveData without previous observers being removed.

Therefore, you must either observe `LiveData` in the `fragment.onCreate()`--which is not really practical, or use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` to get a more reasonable `LifecycleOwner` instance.

For instance, the correct way to observe in `onActivityCreated()` is:

```
timeSheetFragViewModel.selectedWeek.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
        ...
    }
});
```